# How can I automatically submit a form?

Tags: php, forms

I can submit a form without echoing that form. But how can the form be submitted after 5 minutes with the form being echoed?

Here is my code:

```
echo "<form name=myfm id=myfm1 method=post action=ats_exam.php>";
echo "<table width=100%> <tr> <td width=30>&nbsp;<td> <table border=0>";
$n=$_SESSION[qn]+1;
echo "<tR><td><span class=style2>Que ".  $n .": $row[2]</style>";
echo "<tr><td class=style6><input type=radio name=ans value=1>$row[3]";
echo "<tr><td class=style6> <input type=radio name=ans value=2>$row[4]";
echo "<tr><td class=style6><input type=radio name=ans value=3>$row[5]";
echo "<tr><td class=style6><input type=radio name=ans value=4>$row[6]";

if($_SESSION[qn]<mysql_num_rows($rs)-1)
echo "<tr><td><input type=submit name=submit1 value='Next Question'>      </form>";

echo "<tr><td><input type=submit name=submit value='Get Result'>

</form>";
echo "</table></table>";`
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the following:

```
echo "<form name=myfm id=myfm1 method=post action=ats_exam.php>";
echo "<table width=100%> <tr> <td width=30>&nbsp;<td> <table border=0>";
$n=$_SESSION[qn]+1;
echo "<tR><td><span class=style2>Que ".  $n .": $row[2]</style>";
echo "<tr><td class=style6><input type=radio name=ans value=1>$row[3]";
echo "<tr><td class=style6> <input type=radio name=ans value=2>$row[4]";
echo "<tr><td class=style6><input type=radio name=ans value=3>$row[5]";
echo "<tr><td class=style6><input type=radio name=ans value=4>$row[6]";

if($_SESSION[qn]<mysql_num_rows($rs)-1)
echo "<tr><td><input type=submit name=submit1 value='Next Question'>      </form>";

echo "<tr><td><input type=submit name=submit value='Get Result'>

</form>";
echo "</table></table>";`
echo "<script>setInterval(function(){ myform.submit(); }, 3000);</script>";
```

Please check a simple example of how I achieved it here: https://jsfiddle.net/redmutex/4kgde4o4/

Comment: thanks, how will i set the time interval in this code

Comment: Just google for js function setinterval. You can specify time in miliseconds

Comment: for example replace the last line with: `echo "<script>setInterval(function(){ myform.submit(); }, 3000);</script>";` and this should submit the form after 3 seconds.

Comment: did you add the ` name="myform"` in your form opening tag?

Comment: yea, my form name is myfm. please have u review my post ? i have re edited it

Comment: I also updated my answer according to your new question. Please review.

Comment: thanks still not woking, i guess is becaus i have two submit input. to move to he next question and to submit the exam form.

Answer (score -1):

You can use jquery/ajax .get function for this.

```
$.get( "insertdata.php", { page: "add", username: "username" } )
   .done(function( data ) {
    alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
  });
```

Comment: you dont know if she is using jQuery or not.